# R - Return value x after comparing values y with z

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame "test" and "temp" that look like this:

test:

```
    Persnr   Date AmountHolidays
1    55312 201101            0.0
2    55316 201101            3.0
3    55325 201101            0.0
4    76065 201101            0.0
5    71928 201101            1.0
6    72558 201101            0.5
```

temp:

```
     Date Temp
1  201101  4.8
2  201102  0.3
3  201103  8.5
4  201104  8.6
5  201105 14.8
6  201106 15.5
7  201107 17.5
8  201108 19.0
9  201109 13.9
10 201110 10.5
```

What I'd like to have is to compare both Dates from both data frames and take the respective Temp value (from the temp data frame) so I can store it into a new column of data frame "test". This is what the end result should look like:

```
    Persnr   Date AmountHolidays   Temperature
1    55312 201101            0.0   4.8
2    55316 201101            3.0   4.8
3    55325 201101            0.0   4.8
4    76065 201101            0.0   4.8
5    71928 201101            1.0   4.8
6    72558 201101            0.5   4.8
   ....
10   43532 201201            3.0   0.3
11   45324 201201            1.5   0.3
```

I hope my question is clear enough. I think there should be a comparing statement and select the 2nd row of the "temp" data frame. But I'm not sure how to create such statement.

Here's the structure of my data:

```
> str(test)
'data.frame':   490 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Persnr        : num  55312 55316 55325 76065 71928 ...
 $ Date          : num  201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 ...
 $ AmountHolidays: num  0 3 0 0 1 0.5 0 0.5 2 0 ...

> str(temp)
    'data.frame':   60 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ Date: int  201101 201102 201103 201104 201105 201106 201107 201108 201109 201110 ...
     $ Temp: num  4.8 0.3 8.5 8.6 14.8 15.5 17.5 19 13.9 10.5 ...
```

Comment: please use `dput` on your data.frames `test` and `temp`, pasting values like this is not friendly at all for people answering ;)

Comment: Shall do I future. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base `R` you can use `merge`:

```
merge(test, temp, by='Date', all.x=T)
```

Or using `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

setkey(setDT(test), Date)[setDT(temp)]
```

Comment: maybe add all.x=TRUE, to avoid loosing data in test which has no match .. so make it  merge(test, temp, by='Date',all.x=T)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `left_join()` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(test, temp)

#Joining by: "Date"
#  Persnr   Date AmountHolidays Temp
#1  55312 201101            0.0  4.8
#2  55316 201101            3.0  4.8
#3  55325 201101            0.0  4.8
#4  76065 201101            0.0  4.8
#5  71928 201101            1.0  4.8
#6  72558 201101            0.5  4.8
```